# spark streaming fileStream

Tags: scala, streaming, apache-spark

I'm programming with spark streaming but have some trouble with scala. I'm trying to use the function StreamingContext.fileStream

The definition of this function is like this:

```
def fileStream[K, V, F <: InputFormat[K, V]](directory: String)(implicit arg0: ClassManifest[K], arg1: ClassManifest[V], arg2: ClassManifest[F]): DStream[(K, V)]
```

Create a input stream that monitors a Hadoop-compatible filesystem for new files and reads them using the given key-value types and input format. File names starting with . are ignored.
K
Key type for reading HDFS file
V
Value type for reading HDFS file
F
Input format for reading HDFS file
directory
HDFS directory to monitor for new file

I don't know how to pass the type of Key and Value. 
My Code in spark streaming:

```
val ssc = new StreamingContext(args(0), "StreamingReceiver", Seconds(1),
  System.getenv("SPARK_HOME"), Seq("/home/mesos/StreamingReceiver.jar"))

// Create a NetworkInputDStream on target ip:port and count the
val lines = ssc.fileStream("/home/sequenceFile")
```

Java code to write the hadoop file:

```
public class MyDriver {

private static final String[] DATA = { "One, two, buckle my shoe",
        "Three, four, shut the door", "Five, six, pick up sticks",
        "Seven, eight, lay them straight", "Nine, ten, a big fat hen" };

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String uri = args[0];
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(URI.create(uri), conf);
    Path path = new Path(uri);
    IntWritable key = new IntWritable();
    Text value = new Text();
    SequenceFile.Writer writer = null;
    try {
        writer = SequenceFile.createWriter(fs, conf, path, key.getClass(),
                value.getClass());
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            key.set(100 - i);
            value.set(DATA[i % DATA.length]);
            System.out.printf("[%s]\t%s\t%s\n", writer.getLength(), key,
                    value);
            writer.append(key, value);
        }
    } finally {
        IOUtils.closeStream(writer);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What issues are you seeing?  Are you getting compilation errors?  If so, what are they? Are you getting errors/unexpected behavior when you run your code?  If you provide more context into what errors/unexpected behaviors you are seeing you are more likely to get helpful answers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to use `fileStream`, you're going to have to supply all 3 type params to it when calling it.  You need to know what your `Key`, `Value` and `InputFormat` types are before calling it.  If your types were `LongWritable`, `Text` and `TextInputFormat`, you would call `fileStream` like so:

```
val lines = ssc.fileStream[LongWritable, Text, TextInputFormat]("/home/sequenceFile")
```

If those 3 types do happen to be your types, then you might want to use `textFileStream` instead as it does not require any type params and delegates to `fileStream` using those 3 types I mentioned.  Using that would look like this:

```
val lines = ssc.textFileStream("/home/sequenceFile")
```

Comment: Hey i am trying to do the same but with binary files, i have followed the instruction here, unfortunately it does not work. Please could you suggest something? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45778016/reading-binaryfile-with-spark-streaming

Answer (score 2):

```
val filterF = new Function[Path, Boolean] {
    def apply(x: Path): Boolean = {
      val flag = if(x.toString.split("/").last.split("_").last.toLong < System.currentTimeMillis) true else false
      return flag
    }
}

val streamed_rdd = ssc.fileStream[LongWritable, Text, TextInputFormat]("/user/hdpprod/temp/spark_streaming_input",filterF,false).map(_._2.toString).map(u => u.split('\t'))
```