# Scala Spark streaming fileStream

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16560833/spark-streaming-filestream) I'm trying to use `fileStream` but receiving a compile-time error about the type arguments. I'm trying to ingest XML data using `org.apache.mahout.text.wikipedia.XmlInputFormat` provided by `mahout-examples` as my `InputFormat` type.

```
val fileStream = ssc.fileStream[LongWritable, Text, XmlInputFormat](WATCHDIR)
```

The compilation errors are:

```
Error:(39, 26) type arguments [org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable,scala.xml.Text,org.apache.mahout.text.wikipedia.XmlInputFormat] conform to the bounds of none of the overloaded alternatives of
 value fileStream: [K, V, F <: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputFormat[K,V]](directory: String, filter: org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path => Boolean, newFilesOnly: Boolean, conf: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration)(implicit evidence$12: scala.reflect.ClassTag[K], implicit evidence$13: scala.reflect.ClassTag[V], implicit evidence$14: scala.reflect.ClassTag[F])org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.InputDStream[(K, V)] <and> [K, V, F <: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputFormat[K,V]](directory: String, filter: org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path => Boolean, newFilesOnly: Boolean)(implicit evidence$9: scala.reflect.ClassTag[K], implicit evidence$10: scala.reflect.ClassTag[V], implicit evidence$11: scala.reflect.ClassTag[F])org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.InputDStream[(K, V)] <and> [K, V, F <: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputFormat[K,V]](directory: String)(implicit evidence$6: scala.reflect.ClassTag[K], implicit evidence$7: scala.reflect.ClassTag[V], implicit evidence$8: scala.reflect.ClassTag[F])org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.InputDStream[(K, V)]
    val fileStream = ssc.fileStream[LongWritable, Text, XmlInputFormat](WATCHDIR)
                         ^
Error:(39, 26) wrong number of type parameters for overloaded method value fileStream with alternatives:
  [K, V, F <: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputFormat[K,V]](directory: String, filter: org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path => Boolean, newFilesOnly: Boolean, conf: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration)(implicit evidence$12: scala.reflect.ClassTag[K], implicit evidence$13: scala.reflect.ClassTag[V], implicit evidence$14: scala.reflect.ClassTag[F])org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.InputDStream[(K, V)] <and>
  [K, V, F <: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputFormat[K,V]](directory: String, filter: org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path => Boolean, newFilesOnly: Boolean)(implicit evidence$9: scala.reflect.ClassTag[K], implicit evidence$10: scala.reflect.ClassTag[V], implicit evidence$11: scala.reflect.ClassTag[F])org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.InputDStream[(K, V)] <and>
  [K, V, F <: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputFormat[K,V]](directory: String)(implicit evidence$6: scala.reflect.ClassTag[K], implicit evidence$7: scala.reflect.ClassTag[V], implicit evidence$8: scala.reflect.ClassTag[F])org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.InputDStream[(K, V)]
    val fileStream = ssc.fileStream[LongWritable, Text, XmlInputFormat](WATCHDIR)
                     ^
```

I'm very new to Scala, so I'm not really familiar with type classes (I'm assuming that's what's happening here?). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried being explicit? It is using scala.xml.Text, where you should be using org.apache.hadoop.io.Text

Comment: That was it Justin! Wrong type. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Thanks, posted as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception lists that it is searching for `scala.xml.Text`, whereas you need to be using `org.apache.hadoop.io.Text`

Comment: It would have been helpful if the compiler gave a better hint about what it was looking for.